# Puzzled by description of AoA malfunction theory on recent Lion Air accident

Tags: boeing-737

The theory for the recent Lion Air accident states that the AoA sensor malfunctioned and the airplane systems commanded nose down.
Boeing also stated this occurs when the autopilot is disabled. The implication is that the pilots had no input to disable nose down command.
Is this inference correct in the B737-Max?

Comment: Please reword this question in a more generalized fashion so as to not tie it into an accident still under investigation. Please see [this Meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1524/frequent-questions-following-air-incidents) and [this Meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269/should-we-comment-speculate-on-incidents-being-investigated).

Comment: Im putting this on hold until the question is fixed - well done to the 2 answers for not entering into speculation as to the cause of this accident, however sooner or later its likely to happen! If anyone feels like rewording this question to remove references to the specific incident please flag for a moderators attention and we'll be happy to take it off hold. It is a good question aside from the accident speculation.

Comment: Your point well taken.  I will wait and educate myself before posting.  I am an ex private pilot, so will need lots of education here.  The answers were very informative.

Answer (score 2):

The Operations Manual Bulletin put out by Boeing suggests that this is a trim runaway event.  Airspeed and altitude measurements are affected by the angle of attack of the airplane.  The indicated airspeed will be lower in a high angle of attack situation.  The accident airplane was reading a higher angle of attack than reality due to a malfunction of some kind.  The new avionics in the Boeing 737-MAX correct the airspeed measurement for angle of attack so airspeed was reading higher than what it should have been.  As a result the automatic trim, which is set to keep a constant airspeed, kept trying to lower the nose since the reported airspeed was too high.

The 737-MAX Operations Manual Bulletin included procedures to disable the automatic trim.  This runaway trim event occurred during the 3 flights before the accident flight but maintenance was unable to fix the problem.

More information on the accident can be found at the [Aviation Herald](http://avherald.com/h?article=4bf90724&opt=1024).

Answer (score 1):

From a general design perspective, an AOA sensor being involved suggests to me that they suspect the Stall Protection System fired the Stick Pusher.  When you are approaching the stall AOA, you will first get stick shaker (the vibrating doohickey on the control columns) then if it keeps increasing, the pusher will operate and shove the columns full forward, then release.

Before you get to the shaker, if the autopilot is on, the autopilot is supposed disengage itself.

There are two AOA sensors and the computers on board will generally look for agreement so if one sensor goes wonky you get some kind of fault message instead of the airplane responding as if it was stalled.

There is way more than meets the eye here.  Wait a year for the report.

Comment: The 737 does not a have stick pusher.

Comment: Roger.  Pushers are usually only installed when the stall behavior is nasty.